# exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Producttabs_Block_Producttabs'

Tags: blocks, exception

I'm getting the following errors in my exception.log:

```
2015-09-04T04:26:55+00:00 ERR (3):  exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Tipo de bloco inválido: Mage_Producttabs_Block_Producttabs' in /home/my.websiteaddress.com/public_html/app/Mage.php:595 Stack trace: 0 /home/my.websiteaddress.com/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(28247): Mage::throwException('Tipo de bloco i...') 1 /home/my.websiteaddress.com/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(28189): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('producttabs/pro...', Array) 2 /home/my.websiteaddress.com/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(27367): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('producttabs/pro...', NULL, Array) 3 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter->blockDirective(Array) 4 /home/my.websiteaddress.com/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(27037): call_user_func(Array, Array) 5 /home/my.websiteaddress.com/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(27746): Varien_Filter_Template->filter('<div class="mod...') 6 /home/my.websiteaddress.com/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(11124): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter->filter('<div class="mod...') 7 /home/my.websiteaddress.com/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(2613): Mage_Cms_Block_Page->_toHtml() 8 /home/my.websiteaddress.com/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(2331): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml() 9 /home/my.websiteaddress.com/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(2271): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('cms_page', true) ...
```

So my question is, where can I find to add in the module name for this?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the block factory tries to instance a class whose name begins with `Mage` means that the `'producttabs/producttabs'` factory alias isn't properly resolved to the correct class name.

This happens when **configuration isn't up to date** so **clean cache configuration** and verify whether the error still appears.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this error is poped-up after you have installed a new extension (according to errors `Producttabs` is related to that extension) and Magento cant find the block of that extension either due to :

1. Your compilation mode is enabled
2. Extension is not configured properly.

---

**Compilation Mode Problem** : Since compilation mode is ON in your system, it would be the most probable reason for this error. In this case, what you need to do is :

- Remove the extension that you have installed.
- Turn off compilation mode from admin.
- Logout from admin. Then install the extension again.
- Now login again into admin and then clear all cache through admin
- Again turn on compilation again.

**Extension Misconfiguration** : If this is the problem, then very first step is contact the developer of this extension. Or configure block section of the section properly. `config.xml` file is used to do such things.

---

<sup>**Note:** All your inspection should carry out after compilation mode is turned off</sup>